# Laravel4 + Iron io: How to send mail using Mail::queue?

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, iron

I have a laravel app with a form that when it is submitted will send a mail.
The mail configuration is working properly since the mail is received.

But since the process was quite slow i decided to use Queue.

I have set up Iron mq account and set it up on Laravel4.

So instead of `Mail::send` i switch to `Mail::queue`. Here is the code:

```
      return \Mail::queue($this->view, $this->data, function($message) use($self)
    {
        $message->to($self->email, $self->to)->subject($self->subject);
    });
```

And in the routes there is simply:

```
  Route::post('booking', 'HomeController@booking');
  Route::post('rezervesana', 'HomeController@booking'); // This is for the latvian version
```

When i submit the form, the queue is received in Iron mq dashboard and apparently fired.
But no mail is received..

If instead i do something like this:

```
  Route::post('booking', function()
  {
        return Queue::marshal();    
  });
```

Then magically it will work in the latvian version (rezervesana) but of course than the english version page does not even open anymore..

So I am quite confused.

The question is: How can I send properly a mail using `Mail::queue` and how to deal with it in the routes?

I think that the code regarding the `Mail::queue` is correct, what is wrong can be in routes.

So the real question can be: How I have to set up the routes to make queue working properly?
Which is the proper place for `Queue::marshal`?

Thank you guys!
Sorry if it is confused.
Hope you can clarify it to me!

Answer (score 0):

I've used SQS before but not Iron, maybe you should use this?

```
Route::post('booking', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'HomeController@booking'));
```